# Calculation exponential growth with recursion

Tags: recursion

So I'm trying to figure out how to calculate a stock's exponential growth with recursion. The stock's original value, the percentage and the number of years is given by the user.

This is what I thought would work but I was proven wrong. Any ideas?

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String cheese = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Stock price.");
    double v = Double.parseDouble(cheese);

    String mayo = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Percentage.");
    double p = Double.parseDouble(mayo);

    String ham = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Years.");
    double n = Double.parseDouble(ham);

    System.out.println(stockGrowth(v, p, n));
}

static double stockGrowth(double v, double p, double n) {
    if (n > 0) {
        return stockGrowth(v * Math.pow(p, n)) + Math.pow(p, n - 1);
    } else {
        return v;
    }
}
```

Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

If p=0.05 (that is 5%) then one year later v has grown to v*1.05 = v*(1+p).

This leads to the following definition:

```
static double stockGrowth(double v, double p, double n) {
    if (n > 0) {
        return stockGrowth(v * (1+p), p, n - 1);
    } else {
        return v;
    }
}
```